# IDE for C# with unit testing (like Eclipse for Java and assertEquals( ... ) etc. )

Tags: c#, unit-testing, ide

I'd like to test drive C#, and I've seen several posts about free IDEs for C# (including MonoDevelop).

What I have not seen yet is information about the IDEs' capabilities for unit tests. I've been coding in Java, and am reliant on Eclipse's Unit Testing (assertEquals( ... )) etc.) to develop my desk-top code (I know that Eclipse is not the only way to do unit testing in Java, but it does it well).

Is there a similar functionality with any of the IDEs for C#?

Answer (score 4):

Can't say I've used any of the free IDEs myself much, but according to this [blog post](http://www.dijksterhuis.org/using-nunit-with-monodevelop/), MonoDevelop supports [NUnit](http://nunit.org) pretty well. I'd expect most IDEs to support multiple unit test frameworks to be honest - certainly if I were developing a unit test framework, one of the goals would be IDE integration.

Using NUnit with the free "Express" editions of Visual Studio is possible but somewhat painful, in that it uses the separate NUnit GUI instead of being an integrated runner - but it's still better than nothing, of course.

(Personally I've usually used the Professional versions Visual Studio, with [ReSharper](http://jetbrains.com/resharper) and [NCrunch](http://www.ncrunch.net/) running my unit tests.)

Answer (score 2):

There is a [free version of Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express) created by Microsoft, and the latest beta [includes new unit testing features](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FeaturesNOONENOTICEDInVisualStudio11ExpressBetaForWeb.aspx) that was previously only available in the Professional/Ultimate versions.

There are also a lot of [workarounds](http://tech.rofas.net/post/running-and-debugging-tests-with-visual-studio-express-edition.aspx) to the limitations of unit testing in the free version of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there is an IDE [test runner plugin](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/InsideSharpDevelop.Samples-GallioAddin.ashx) for [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/) that uses MBUnit and Gallio. The first link is to an article that mentions how to set things up.

Comment: +1 for MBUnit and Gallio. I like it much better than NUnit or MSTest.

Answer (score 1):

[SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/) supports Unit testing with NUnit, and of course supports C#.